# How to resolve "pure virtual method called"

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class, pure-virtual

I understand why this is happening, but I'm stuck trying to resolve it...here is what my code is doing when the error is generated (thus, leading to a crash) when my program exits...

`pure virtual method called`

```
SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
   BaseClassObject->SomePureVirtualMethod(this);
}
```

---

```
void DerivedClass::SomePureVirtualMethod(SomeClass* obj)
{
    //Do stuff to remove obj from a collection
}
```

I never have a call to `new SomeClass` but I have a `QList<SomeClass*>` which I append `SomeClass*` objects to.  The purpose of this destructor in `SomeClass` is to tell `DerivedClass` to remove a specific instance of `SomeClass` from it's collection of `QList<SomeClass*>`.

So, in a concrete example...

`BaseClass` = `Shape`

`DerivedClass` = `Triangle`

`SomeClass` = `ShapeProperties` which owns a reference to `Shape`

So, I never have a call to `new ShapeProperties` but I have a `QList<ShapeProperties*>` inside of `Triangle`.  The destructor in `ShapeProperties` is to tell `Triangle` to remove a specific property of `ShapeProperties` from it's collection of `QList<ShapeProperties*>`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By the time your destructor is called, the destructor of inherited classes has already been called. Within constructors and destructors, the dynamic type of the object can effectively be considered to be the same as the static type. That is, when you call virtual methods from within your constructors/destructors it's not the overriden versions of them that are called.

If `SomePureVirtualMethod` needs to be called at the destructor, then you will have to call it within the destructor of the class where the actual definition of the method you want is.

Comment: Then how do I know which instance of `this` I'm referring to if I call it with in the derived constructor?

Comment: I probably misunderstood this, "If `SomePureVirtualMethod` needs to be called at the destructor, then you will have to call it within the destructor of the class where the actual definition of the method you want is."

Comment: @user869525: In simple words, your call to `SomePureVirtualMethod` from a destructor won't resolve to the most derived override. If you want to call the most derived override, you have to call it from the destructor of the class that implements such override.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but it doesn't resolve my issue since I'm in `SomeClass`, not `BaseClass` nor `DerivedClass`.`SomeClass` owns an instance of `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` owns a `list` of `SomeClass`.  The destructor in `SomeClass` needs to remove an instance of `SomeClass` from the `list` inside of `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 15):

When you call the `virtual` method in the destructor of the Base class `SomeClass` it calls the method(`SomePureVirtualMethod()`) of the Base class `SomeClass` which is a pure virtual method with no definition. And hence the error.

**Why does this happen?**
The type of `this` in constructor or destructor is of the type whose constructor or destructor is being called and hence dynamic dispatch doesn't work in constructors and destructors as you would expect it to work in all other functions.

**Why does it crash?**
Because calling a pure virtual function from constructor or destructor is an **Undefined Behavior**.

**C++03 10.4/6 states**

> "Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined."

**How to avoid it?**
Just ensure that you don't call a pure virtual function from constructor or destructor.
Don't call `virtual` methods in constructor or destructor unless you understand the dynamics involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is another reason why this might happen, depending on your compiler and system, and that is from a dangling reference. [Paul S. R. Chisholm explains](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/pure_virtual.html) the possible state of freed memory:

> - The memory might be marked as deallocated.
> - The memory might be deliberately scrambled.
> - The memory might be reused.
> - The memory might have been left exactly the way it was.
>
> The last is an interesting case. What was the object "exactly the way
> it was"? In this case, it was an instance of the abstract base class;
> certainly that's the way the vtbl was left. What happens if we try to
> call a pure virtual member function for such an object?
>
> "Pure virtual function called".