# qtcreator opencv application exits on button click with error message

Tags: opencv, qt5, qt-creator, desktop-application

When I run my opencv application in qt and I don't display any images and then I click exit, the program outputs this.

```
Starting /home/ubuntu/Documents/opencvWork/OpencvInterface/build-OpencvInterface-Desktop-Release/OpencvInterface...
/home/ubuntu/Documents/opencvWork/OpencvInterface/build-OpencvInterface-Desktop-Release/OpencvInterface exited with code 0
```

This is what happens when I select an image to be displayed by the application, then I hit exit.

```
Starting /home/ubuntu/Documents/opencvWork/OpencvInterface/build-OpencvInterface-Desktop-Release/OpencvInterface...
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/ubuntu/Documents/opencvWork/OpencvInterface/build-OpencvInterface-Desktop-Release/OpencvInterface crashed
```

Here is the code that I'm using to close the windows that pop up. I'm also using imshow in opencv to display the images, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem.

```
void opencv_Window::on_DestroyWindowButton_clicked()
{
    destroyAllWindows();
}

void opencv_Window::on_ExitButton_clicked()
{
    destroyAllWindows();
    close();
}
```

Comment: The error seems to happen when your image is being loaded and shown, can you show the code that does that?

Comment: I use regular imshow("foo", bar); for displaying images

By load I assume you mean imread?

Comment: I mean where you call it, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10707286/1771479, which has the same error.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/suzobanado.coffee

Like this? And I will check out your link. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Actually it would be better to edit the question and give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), by doing that it will also be easier to debug.