# Compiler option to disable calling pure virtual methods from constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Referring to this question, [How to resolve "pure virtual method called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707286/how-to-resolve-pure-virtual-method-called) is there a compiler option, that raises error when a virtual method is called from constructor/destructor? When there is a pure virtual method, the program will crash at runtime with segmentation fault.

This is proven many times to be a bad design:

> When you call virtual methods from within your constructors/destructors it's not the overriden versions of them that are called.

**EDIT:**

I am asking specifically for MSVC, but it would be useful if there is an option for each compiler (GCC, CLANG, etc).

Comment: Which compiler specifically?

Comment: I added this information.

Comment: Re "this is proven many times to be a bad design", yes, directly and explicitly invoking UB is bad design. However your quote doesn't support that. So that entire paragraph is Bad Logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a compiler option that raises error when a virtual method is called from constructor/destructor?  When there is a pure virtual method, the program will crash at runtime with segmentation fault.
>
> but it would be useful if there is an option for each compiler (GCC, CLANG, etc).

For GCC and Clang, the option is `-Werror`. This will cause all warnings to raise an error. If you directly call a pure virtual function in a constructor or destructor, both compilers warn by default.

There is of course no warning / error if a non-pure virtual function is called. It has well defined behaviour. Also, a compiler can not in general detect indirect calls to pure virtual functions.

I don't know of MSVC.

> This is proven many times to be a bad design:

If you refer to calling a pure virtual function virtually in ctor./dtor., then *bad design* is an understatement. The behaviour is undefined. If you're unlucky, the program might not even crash.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf about your edit: Is it even possible to call a function virtually in c-/d-tor? As I understand, the call is always non-virtual, and that is why it is wrong since pure virtual functions might not even have a definition.

Comment: Yes, unqualified calls of virtual functions are *always* virtual. However, in the constructor of a class T the **dynamic type** is T. And that means that virtual calls, e.g. from base class functions, will at most go down to T's implementation of the relevant functions.

Comment: I've posted an [SO question about the aspect that has me in doubt here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645853/calling-class-ts-implementation-of-pure-virtual-from-t-constructor-without-qual). Possibly due to lack of coffeee - I'm out of coffee! But still.

Comment: I got [verification that the behavior is indeed UB in all cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645853/calling-class-ts-implementation-of-pure-virtual-from-t-constructor-without-qual#42646077), as your answer implies.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any compiler switch for this in visual studio, but there is a handler in the Visual Studio Runtime for this: **_purecall** , which is located in the runtime file **PureVirt.c** . It will be called every time when there is no entry in the vtable for a virtual function, which is the case when you have a pure virtual call.

You can overload this function and add a **DebugBreak**

But this is just a workaround to get the callstack for your pure virtual call.