# Calling class T's implementation of pure virtual from T constructor without qualification?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

Considering that a virtual call of a `T` member function (directly or indirectly) from a constructor of a class `T`, can at most go down to `T`'s implementation, does the following code, with *unqualified call*, have Undefined Behavior or not?

Note, to avoid noise: if you believe that member functions are not called virtually when invoked from a constructor, then please don't answer or comment here, but raise that issue in a separate SO question. Thank you.

```
struct Baze
{
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    Baze(){ foo(); bar(); }
};

void Baze::foo() {}
void Baze::bar() {}

struct Derived: Baze
{
    void bar() override {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived{};
}
```

Comment: You issued contradictory instructions to a potential class of downvoters: they should explain their vote whilst not commenting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is covered by `[class.abstract]/6` (N4140):

> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a
>   virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed)
>   from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.

So even though you have provided a definition for the pure virtual function, it's still technically UB.

There is a Core Working Group issue which addresses this [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#230). It seems that the rules are unlikely to change to make this well-defined.

Comment: Thanks, that seems clear. Problem is that both g++ and Visual C++ compile that code, with no warning (not even from g++, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  It's UB, not ill-formed.  (In your example, it is clear that the pure virtual will be called, but if the call to `bar` was from another function that would never actually call `bar` from the constructor - but could when called from other functions - then it would be trickier.)

Comment: Thanks for the DR reference. :)